# Elasticsearch (version 2.3) Function Score Query with filtered type query

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am very new to elastic search, We are migrating from Solr to elastic-search. As part of migration working converting existing Solr query to elastic-search DSL query.

Here is the DSL query I have partially completed using function score feature.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "match": {
            "name": "barack obama"
          },
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "relevance": {
                "gte": 6
              }
            },
            "bool": {
              "must_not": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "classIds": [
                      199,
                      220
                    ],
                    "execution": "and"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "classIds": 10597
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "lang": "groovy",
              "file": "calculate-score",
              "params": {
                "relevance_boost": 1,
                "class_penalize": 0.25
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This query returning error while am running against elastic-search cluster. Please help me to figure out the issue.

Here calculate-score is groovy script and its working fine, I tested that with simple query.

Here is the error response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "query_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[filtered] query does not support [match]",
        "index": "nodes_5e27a7d3-b370-40bd-9e71-cf04a36297c0",
        "line": 6,
        "col": 11
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "nodes_5e27a7d3-b370-40bd-9e71-cf04a36297c0",
        "node": "NOAwAtVwQS25egu7AIaHEg",
        "reason": {
          "type": "query_parsing_exception",
          "reason": "[filtered] query does not support [match]",
          "index": "nodes_5e27a7d3-b370-40bd-9e71-cf04a36297c0",
          "line": 6,
          "col": 11
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Here is Solr query I am trying to convert to elastic-search:

```
SOLR QUERY (UNIQUE_NODE_CORE): q={!boost b="product(pow(field(relevance),1.0000),if(exists(query({!v='all_class_ids:226'})),0.25,1),if(exists(query({!v='all_class_ids:14106'})),0.25,1),if(exists(query({!v='all_class_ids:656'})),0.25,1))"}
raw_name:"barack obama"
&rows=1
&start=0
&sort=score desc,relevance desc
-&fq=class_id:"10597"
-fq=relevance:[6 TO *]
-&fq=-all_class_ids:"14127"
-&fq=-all_class_ids:"14106"
-&fq=-all_class_ids:"226"
&fl=ontology_id,url_friendly_name,name,score,raw_notable_for,property_207578
```

Just need help to run filtered query with function score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great job, you're almost there, you're just missing a `query` section inside your `filtered` query in order to wrap the `match` query. As well, the `range` filter can be inserted into the `bool/must`. Quite a mouthful, I know.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "name": "barack obama"
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "classIds": [
                      199,
                      220
                    ],
                    "execution": "and"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "relevance": {
                      "gte": 6
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "classIds": 10597
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "lang": "groovy",
              "file": "calculate-score",
              "params": {
                "relevance_boost": 1,
                "class_penalize": 0.25
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that since ES 2.0 the `filtered` query is deprecated and you can rewrite it with a `bool/must/filter` query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "match": {
              "name": "barack obama"
            }
          },
          "filter": [
            {
              "range": {
                "relevance": {
                  "gte": 6
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "classIds": 10597
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "classIds": [
                  199,
                  220
                ],
                "execution": "and"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "lang": "groovy",
              "file": "calculate-score",
              "params": {
                "relevance_boost": 1,
                "class_penalize": 0.25
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey can you look at this issue for me, facing performance issue when try to use groovy function score: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871163/elasticsearch-query-with-function-score-is-running-more-than-10-times-slower