# ElasticSearch Query with function score is running more than 10 times slower

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, groovy

Here is my query without function score:

```
{
  "from": 200,
  "size": 25,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
    "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "query": {
                    "terms": {
                      "cotypes.id": [
                        199
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "path": "cotypes"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "relevance": {
                    "from": 6,
                    "to": null,
                    "include_lower": true,
                    "include_upper": true
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "must_not": {
              "terms": {
                "ontologyId": [
                  1314696,
                  1314691
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "name.nameStandard": {
            "query": "john smith",
            "type": "boolean",
            "boost": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query return the response in ~250ms.

But I need to add some boost factor for improve the default scoring. I modified the query to use the function score, but after that query taking too long (~3000ms)

Here is the function score query:

```
{
  "from": 200,
  "size": 25,
  "query": {
  "function_score": {
    "query": {
    "bool": {
    "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "query": {
                    "terms": {
                      "cotypes.id": [
                        199
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "path": "cotypes"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "relevance": {
                    "from": 6,
                    "to": null,
                    "include_lower": true,
                    "include_upper": true
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "must_not": {
              "terms": {
                "ontologyId": [
                  1314696,
                  1314691
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "name.nameStandard": {
            "query": "john smith",
            "type": "boolean",
            "boost": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
    "functions": [
      {
        "script_score": {
          "script": {
            "file": "calculate-score",
            "lang": "groovy",
            "params": {
              "relevance_boost": 0.5
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "boost_mode": "sum"
  }
}
}
```

calculate-score.groovy script given below:

```
def penalize = 1
def penalizeClassDict = [
    '226': 0.25,
    '14106': 0.25,
    '656': 0.25
   ]
for (item in _source.cotypes)
{
    if(penalizeClassDict.containsKey(item.id.toString()))
        penalize = penalize * penalizeClassDict[ item.id.toString()]
}
_score + (pow(_source.relevance, relevance_boost)) * 1
```

Please help me to make the query perform better!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: how does `penalize` affect the score ?

Comment: Yea,  that i have changed for testing something, actually instead of * 1, It will be * penalize. But that is not the problem here..

Comment: the reason i asked is for the above script logic replacing script_score with field_value_factor is possible if  `relevance_boost` is always 0.5 .Doing away with script_score is one way to improve performance

Comment: I need the function score/script score, I have some other complicated logic to implement later once this issue fixed, and query is slow only if we match against a analyzed field, in this case am using standard analyzer.

Comment: the question gives  the impression adding "function_score" i.e "script_score" made the query 10 times slower. Hence harping on the `script` , in the script it looks like you are using `_scource.cotypes`  would it be possible to index cotypes and use doc . As mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_source_field) _source is slower.

Comment: Okie let me try that! Thank you @keety

Comment: @keety: do we need to index integer fields cotypes.id is actually an integer field?

Comment: as long as  would have set it to type integer in the mapping you should be fine example mapping would be something on these lines `{"cotypes":{"properties":{"id":{"type":"integer"}}}}`

Comment: also it maybe useful to post the current mapping for the document ?

Comment: Yea i am working on it, since am using _source its slower i guess,  now i am  changing it to doc['classIds'] and doc['relevance'] in the script, since am using "cotypes", array of object, creating fresh index with classIds[] so i can refer that doc['classIds']. doc only support basic data type and arrays, wont support json. I am waiting to finish the indexing, once tested it i will let you know.

Comment: sounds good, gd luck!